# Where is file_lock stored in Linux

Tags: linux

I'm reading the *Understand the Linux Kernel* book, and it says that the list of `file_lock` is stored in the file's inode (of field `i_flock`).

But in the `sys_flock()` of `Linux 2.6.11.12`, which will eventually call `flock_lock_file()`. It uses `filp->f_dentry->d_inode->i_flock` to get the list of  `file_lock` and `filp->f_dentry` is an `dentry` of the directory which "contains" the file.

```
int flock_lock_file(struct file *filp, struct file_lock *new_fl) {
    // ...
    struct inode * inode = filp->f_dentry->d_inode;
    // ...
}
```

Suppose that the `file_lock` list are linked with `filp->f_dentry->d_inode->i_flock`, What will happen when a hard link exists:

```
/some_path/foo/file.txt
/another_path/bar/file_link
```

and file_link is a hard link to file.txt

When we use this two path to `open` the same file, `sys_open()` will set `filp->f_dentry` to `foo` and `bar` separately, isn't it? If my guess is right, how `file_lock` can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file_lock` is indeed stored in the `inode` of the corresponding file.

An `inode` can be referred by several directory entries, which linked in inode's `i_dentry` field. Even for a unique file might have different `filp->f_dentry`, `filp->f_dentry->d_inode` is all refer to the same inode.